# Posting string encoded with htmlentities back to the server

Tags: php, post, html-entities

I generate this in a view:

```
<form method="post">
       <input type="hidden" 
              name="test" 
              value="<?=htmlentities('<>"&ščé', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>">
       <input type="submit>
</form>
```

Now, should I do this when processing data from the form?

```
$decodedTest = html_entity_decode($_POST['test'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

I think that this should be allright:

```
$decodedTest = $_POST['test'];
```

But I have not found a reference to this.

EDIT: I had printed the posted value of `test` and I had seen that the value is not encoded. What I don't know is If I can *rely* on this behaviour and why. I am asking about theory of operation. If I look into the raw post request, I can see that the post data is urlencoded (which is I guess a different type of encoding than htmlentities does). Does that mean that client must perform some recoding before sending the request. Does (client) browser store input values in encoded form or decoded form in memory before sending? (I already know that php automatically decodes urlencoded data in requests so that part is fairly clear to me).

Comment: Read up on "Cross-site scripting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a reference because printing `htmlspecialchars($_POST['test'])` (or just setting `Content-Type: text/plain`) will immediately reveal that the data inside $_POST is not entity-encoded.

You also don't need to call `htmlentities` to encode the data in the view -- `htmlspecialchars` will suffice if your aim is to generate valid markup.

Comment: @clime: You can rely on this, yes. Unfortunately you can call PHP many things but over-specified is not one of them, so AFAIK there is no reference to back this up. It's just how it is. The client urlencodes data so that it adheres to the HTTP specifiation. It doesn't matter how it keeps data in memory (although of course it would keep them raw).

Answer (score 0):

Sending the form, you can do it. Better check